# Facebook event when click like page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i  want know when i click like page in facebook have event or notification of facebook api let me know that event and use it to send notification to my app ?
Thanks for any help !

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mxXY2/1/

Comment: Thank you,but i mean when i click like in "another page facebook" in internet, how i can catch event that and send notification to my app (not like button on my app)